# Stop Eclipse from clearing console

Tags: java, eclipse

Just as the title says, when I run my program it deletes the output from running the program the last time. I have tried going into preferences and disabling the limit on console output, and deselected the "remove terminated launches when a new launch is created" box. Any other ideas? For example: If my output in the console reads "Hello", how could I keep that "Hello" in the console when I run my program again? So in the end it would read "Hello"
"Hello"

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to do this ... apart from modifying Eclipse yourself.

Suggestion: run the application *outside* of Eclipse; e.g. at the command prompt.

Comment: Damn, okay thanks. I'm doing a project that takes input and prints something out, and it would make printing it (physically) a lot easier. Thanks though!

Comment: Do you have any idea if other IDE's will not clear the console, or is that just a standard thing?

Comment: I only use Eclipse, so I can't answer that.  However, given that the purpose of an IDE is code *development",  I'd *expect* them all to behave this way, at least by default.

Comment: jGRASP appends each console log to the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running on a server (e.g., tomcat) from within Eclipse you can go to the *Server* view, double-click your server, click *Open launch configuration*, then *Common*, then *Output file*. From there you can specify an output destination on your file system or in your Eclipse workspace.

This doesn't answer your question exactly, but addresses your subsequent comment re: printing.